# Which is better for performance: NVL or CASE WHEN X IS NULL for Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have often heard that for AWS Redshift use of `nvl` is sub-optimal. Use of `case when X is null` is preferred over `nvl`. I searched over it, and for ORACLE/SQL it is same for performance, however this is specific to Redshift (not even PostGres).

For e.g.: 
Not optimal;

```
select nvl(X,Y),Z from table1;
```

Preferred:

```
select case when X is null then Y else X end, Z from table1;
```

Is this claim correct? Kindly elaborate extensively on the reason whether this claim is correct or not.

Comment: I do not know this specific case, but - in general - this is probably related to *sargability*.

Comment: use explain analyze on a query involving nvl and the equivalent using case statement, and examine the output in https://explain.depesz.com/